# Optimising F# answer for Euler #4

Tags: performance, algorithm, f#

I have recently begun learning F#. Hoping to use it to perform any mathematically heavy algorithms in C# applications and to broaden my knowledge

I have so far avoided StackOverflow as I didn't want to see the answer to this until I came to one myself.

I want to be able to write very efficient F# code, focused on performance and then maybe in other ways, such as writing in F# concisely (number of lines etc.).

Project Euler Question 4:

> *A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.*
>
> *Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.*

My Answer:

```
let IsPalindrome (x:int) = if x.ToString().ToCharArray() = Array.rev(x.ToString().ToCharArray()) then x else 0

let euler4 = [for i in [100..999] do
            for j in [i..999] do yield i*j]
                |> Seq.filter(fun x -> x = IsPalindrome(x)) |> Seq.max |> printf "Largest product of two 3-digit numbers is %d"
```

I tried using `option` and returning `Some(x)` and `None` in `IsPalindrome` but kept getting compiling errors as I was passing in an `int` and returning `int option`. I got a NullRefenceException trying to return `None.Value`.
Instead I return 0 if the number isn't a palindrome, these 0's go into the Sequence, unfortunately.

Maybe I could order the sequence and then get the top value? instead of using Seq.Max? Or filter out results > 1?

Would this be better? Any advice would be much appreciated, even if it's general F# advice.

Comment: one thing that jumps out at me is that you'll be repeating a lot of multiplications this way. There's no need to calculate both `101 * 100` and `100 * 101`. You can do something like `for j in [i..999]` to fix that.

Comment: That's brilliant! Thanks @RedAlert I will update my answer so that more suggested improvements can come from this. I tested it out and it returns the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
/// handy extension for reversing a string
type System.String with
    member s.Reverse() = String(Array.rev (s.ToCharArray()))

let isPalindrome x = let s = string x in s = s.Reverse()

seq {
    for i in 100..999 do
    for j in   i..999 -> i * j
}
|> Seq.filter isPalindrome
|> Seq.max
|> printfn "The answer is: %d"
```

Comment: I can really see the improvement through this method! Is this using #light? I like the extension of System.String. Does this modify the existing String type? adding the reverse method to it essentially? This does as I had thought about, put the answers in descending order, elimination the need for `Seq.max`

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand `{ 999 .. -1 .. 100 }` however. I'm assuming it creates a sequence from 999 to 100, but what does the middle `-1` value do? I'd be happy to read up on it.

Comment: Yes, you could say that, although `#light` is the default. `Reverse` is a type extension. You can [read about those on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233211.aspx).

Comment: `{ 999 .. -1 .. 100 }` means _a sequence of numbers starting at 999 and decrementing by 1 until ending at 100_.

Comment: The `-1` is the step size to use for the range.

Comment: I see. Thanks all. From this I deduce that {100..999} is a short-form of {100..1..999}. I will read up on Type Extensions.

Comment: Testing this out I had to replace `Seq.head` with `Seq.max` to get the answer. The head returns 580085 oddly for me. I will look into why this is.

Comment: You're right. Sorry, silly mistake. That's because `999 * 1` would come before a larger product like `998 * 999` in the sequence. Since we have to use `Seq.max` anyway, the order of the numbers doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes I see that. Thanks for updating your answer!

Comment: I shortened my answer a bit and reduced the number of products compared by `Seq.max`.

Comment: So basically we're back to where you started, with some minor tidying up. :)

Answer (score 4):

Efficiency being a primary concern, using string allocation/manipulation to find a numeric palindrome seems misguided – here's my approach:

```
module NumericLiteralG =
    let inline FromZero () = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
    let inline FromOne () = LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne

module Euler =
    let inline isNumPalindrome number =
        let ten = 1G + 1G + 1G + 1G + 1G + 1G + 1G + 1G + 1G + 1G
        let hundred = ten * ten
        let rec findHighDiv div =
            let div' = div * ten
            if number / div' = 0G then div else findHighDiv div'
        let rec impl n div =
            div = 0G || n / div = n % ten && impl (n % div / ten) (div / hundred)
        findHighDiv 1G |> impl number

    let problem004 () =
        { 100 .. 999 }
        |> Seq.collect (fun n -> Seq.init (1000 - n) ((+) n >> (*) n))
        |> Seq.filter isNumPalindrome
        |> Seq.max
```

Comment: Likewise for @Luka Rahne's answer I'll have to look into this more. Thank you for your answer! Having different approaches to look at is a huge help.

Comment: How about moving `ten` and `hundred` outside `isNumPalindrome` so they only get evaluated once? (unless the compiler is smarter than me and already does this...)

Comment: @mydogisbox : Indeed, the compiler already treats them as folded constants, even with optimizations disabled, at least for primitive scalar types. Also, if they were moved outside of the inline function they could no longer be generic values (`isNumPalindrome` is inline so that its argument type can be `int`, `ulong`, `BigInteger`, etc).

Comment: Any reason for such a complex initial sequence initialization? Functional programming is nice but this looks a bit like an overkill (+ not so efficient one with concat in the picture as well).

Comment: @Klark : It's what's intuitive to me - others' opinions may vary. The point of the answer was the process of checking for a palindrome, not the sequence initialization.

Comment: Agree, your's solution is more efficient than the other ones (thus the upvote :)). I was just a bit puzzled by the seq init part. Seq {} / nested for loops are far, far more intuitive, at least to me.

Comment: @Klark : I'm pretty sure I've never written a for loop in F#. Even in C++, which is my primary language, I strictly prefer algorithms and higher-order functions. To each their own, I guess. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn could you make a function which returned ten and hundred in a generic fashion, so you only have to do `let ten, hundred = MakeTenAndHundred()` instead of spelling it out each time?

Comment: @mydogisbox : Sure, you could, but it would only save one line of code, and again, the values are already folded constants in the IL so there would be absolutely zero runtime difference, so I don't see the point...

Comment: @ildjarn I was thinking it would be more readable with less room for error in the case where you were writing an entire generic library

Comment: Can you tell me what `(+) 100` and `(*) n` do? They seem to be functions that follow some sort of shorthand notation. I've been googling extensively but can't find anything written about this.

Comment: @DropTheTable : Any operator can be used as a normal function by wrapping it in parenthesis. I.e., `x + y` is identical to `(+) x y`. So in this case, since both `+` and `*` are binary operators, partial function application is being used to add 100 to the argument from the first `Seq.init` and multiply `n` by a value, respectively. But again, the point of this answer was the process of checking for a palindrome, not initializing the sequence. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn Ah I see now, obvious with an explanation :P Thank you for clearing this up. That part was all that i needed to understand your solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
let IsPalindrom (str:string)=
  let rec fn(a,b)=a>b||str.[a]=str.[b]&&fn(a+1,b-1)
  fn(0,str.Length-1)
let IsIntPalindrome = (string>>IsPalindrom)
let sq={100..999}
sq|>Seq.map (fun x->sq|>Seq.map (fun y->(x,y),x*y))
  |>Seq.concat|>Seq.filter (snd>>IsIntPalindrome)|>Seq.maxBy (snd)
```

Comment: I really like the look of this solution, it being recursive. However when I run it I get the answer 999.

Comment: ops.. Sorry Im not correct translit your main post (my native lang russian). Correcting code...

Comment: No problem, thank you very much. Great solution, even shows the two 2-digit numbers which multiply to get the answer!

Answer (score 0):

just my solution:

```
let isPalin x =
    x.ToString() = new string(Array.rev (x.ToString().ToCharArray()))
let isGood num seq1 = Seq.exists (fun elem -> (num % elem = 0 && (num / elem) < 999)) seq1
{998001 .. -1 .. 10000} |> Seq.filter(fun x -> isPalin x) |> Seq.filter(fun x -> isGood x {999 .. -1 .. 100}) |> Seq.nth 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see you start with already having multiplied 100*100 and 999*999. It is my understanding that it's fine to create a bigger sequence using this? As it's a sequence and not a list or set? This works well except if you wanted to change the input parameters.

Comment: sequences are lazy, so it doesn't matter how big it is

Comment: this looks even worse than the naive brute force solution. You are creating an `n^2` sequence to start, and then performing `n` divisions on each element as part of your test. That's `O(n^3)`, vs OP's `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

- simplest way is to go from 999 to 100, because is much likley to be product of two large numbers.
- j can then start from i because other way around was already tested
- other optimisations would go in directions where multiplactions would go descending order, but that makes everything little more difficult. In general it is expressed as list mergeing.

Haskell  (my best try in functional programming)

```
merge f x [] = x
merge f [] y = y
merge f (x:xs) (y:ys)
               | f x y     =  x : merge f xs     (y:ys) 
               | otherwise =  y : merge f (x:xs)   ys 

compare_tuples (a,b) (c,d) = a*b >= c*d

gen_mul n = (n,n) : merge compare_tuples 
                         ( gen_mul (n-1) ) 
                         ( map (\x -> (n,x)) [n-1,n-2 .. 1] )

is_product_palindrome (a,b) = x == reverse x where x = show (a*b)

main = print $ take 10 $  map ( \(a,b)->(a,b,a*b) ) 
   $ filter is_product_palindrome $  gen_mul 9999
```

output  (less than 1s)- first 10 palindromes  =>

```
[(9999,9901,99000099),
 (9967,9867,98344389),
 (9999,9811,98100189),
 (9999,9721,97200279),
 (9999,9631,96300369),
 (9999,9541,95400459),
 (9999,9451,94500549),
 (9767,9647,94222249),
 (9867,9547,94200249),
 (9999,9361,93600639)]
```

One can see that this sequence is lazy generated from large to small

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this does go over my head somewhat :P I will study it further.

Comment: Edited: code is now simple to understand, way more efficient and likley correct

Answer (score 0):

Optimized version:

```
let Euler dgt=
  let [mine;maxe]=[dgt-1;dgt]|>List.map (fun x->String.replicate x "9"|>int)
  let IsPalindrom (str:string)=
    let rec fn(a,b)=a>b||str.[a]=str.[b]&&fn(a+1,b-1)
    fn(0,str.Length-1)
  let IsIntPalindrome = (string>>IsPalindrom)
  let rec fn=function
    |x,y,max,a,_ when a=mine->x,y,max
    |x,y,max,a,b when b=mine->fn(x,y,max,a-1,maxe)
    |x,y,max,a,b->a*b|>function
                   |m when b=maxe&&m<max->x,y,max
                   |m when m>max&&IsIntPalindrome(m)->fn(a,b,m,a-1,maxe)
                   |m when m>max->fn(x,y,max,a,b-1)
                   |_->fn(x,y,max,a-1,maxe)
  fn(0,0,0,maxe,maxe)
```

Log (switch #time on):

```
> Euler 2;;
Real: 00:00:00.004, CPU: 00:00:00.015, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
val it : int * int * int = (99, 91, 9009)
> Euler 3;;
Real: 00:00:00.004, CPU: 00:00:00.015, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
val it : int * int * int = (993, 913, 906609)
> Euler 4;;
Real: 00:00:00.002, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
val it : int * int * int = (9999, 9901, 99000099)
> Euler 5;;
Real: 00:00:00.702, CPU: 00:00:00.686, GC gen0: 108, gen1: 1, gen2: 0
val it : int * int * int = (99793, 99041, 1293663921) //int32 overflow
```

Extern to BigInteger:

```
let Euler dgt=
  let [mine;maxe]=[dgt-1;dgt]|>List.map (fun x->new System.Numerics.BigInteger(String.replicate x "9"|>int))
  let IsPalindrom (str:string)=
    let rec fn(a,b)=a>b||str.[a]=str.[b]&&fn(a+1,b-1)
    fn(0,str.Length-1)
  let IsIntPalindrome = (string>>IsPalindrom)
  let rec fn=function
    |x,y,max,a,_ when a=mine->x,y,max
    |x,y,max,a,b when b=mine->fn(x,y,max,a-1I,maxe)
    |x,y,max,a,b->a*b|>function
                   |m when b=maxe&&m<max->x,y,max
                   |m when m>max&&IsIntPalindrome(m)->fn(a,b,m,a-1I,maxe)
                   |m when m>max->fn(x,y,max,a,b-1I)
                   |_->fn(x,y,max,a-1I,maxe)
  fn(0I,0I,0I,maxe,maxe)
```

Check:

```
Euler 5;;
Real: 00:00:02.658, CPU: 00:00:02.605, GC gen0: 592, gen1: 1, gen2: 0
val it :
  System.Numerics.BigInteger * System.Numerics.BigInteger *
  System.Numerics.BigInteger =
  (99979 {...}, 99681 {...}, 9966006699 {...})
```